# jQuery - Select last element of a group with the same ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, selector

I have a form/table that is dynamically altered via JS by adding/removing rows (form inputs). I want to create a column that counts the number of rows, so I tried using,

```
$("#rowcount:last").replaceWith( "<td>" + newNum + "</td>" );
```

to change the counter columns last element to the new number, but the ':last' selector doesn't seem to work in this case. Here is my code for reference (sorry for the ugliness of my form. I tried to make it look as pretty as I could, but because of my limited experience, it still looks like it was slapped on the wrong side at birth):

```
<html>

<head>
<title></title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.maskedinput.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#btnAdd').click(function() {
            var num     = $('.ccinput').length; // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
            var newNum  = new Number(num + 1);      // the numeric ID of the new input field being added

            // create the new element via clone(), and manipulate it's ID using newNum value
            var newElem = $('#input' + num).clone().attr('id', 'input' + newNum);

            // insert the new element after the last "duplicatable" input field
            $('#input' + num).after(newElem);
            $("#rowcount").replaceWith( "<td>" + newNum + "</td>" );

            // enable the "remove" button
            $('#btnDel').attr('disabled','');

            $("*#date").mask("99/99/9999");

            // business rule: you can only add 20 names
            if (newNum == 20)
                $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled','disabled');
        });

        $('#btnDel').click(function() {
            var num = $('.ccinput').length; // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
            $('#input' + num).remove();     // remove the last element

            // enable the "add" button
            $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled','');

            // if only one element remains, disable the "remove" button
            if (num-1 == 1)
                $('#btnDel').attr('disabled','disabled');
        });

        $("*#date").mask("99/99/9999");
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlentities($PHP_SELF); ?>">
<table border="1" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<th></th>
<th># (last four digits)</th>
<th>Amount</th>
<th>Approval</th>
<th>Date Received</th>
</tr>
<tbody>
    <tr id="input1" class="ccinput">
    <td id="rowcount"> 1 </td>
    <td> <input id="cnum" type="text" name="cc_num[]" maxlength="4" /> </td> 
    <td> <input id="camnt" type="int" name="cc_amnt[]" /> </td>
    <td> <input id="appr" type="text" name="cc_app[]" maxlength="10" /> </td> 
    <td> <input id="date" type="text" name="cc_date[]" /> </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<div>
    <input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="Add" />
    <input type="button" id="btnDel" value="Remove" />
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `:))` your HTML becomes invalid if you have same multiple `id` in your DOM,

Comment: The HTML seems to run fine with multiple IDs, the only issue is that I can only get it to select the first ID or all of the element, but not the last ID. I'm not sure why this is happening. Again, this is literally the first thing I've written in HTML/JS, so my knowledge is very limited.

$("*#date") masks all the date inputs to a 99/99/9999 format using masked input plugin for jQuery.

Comment: I should add, the reason I need multiple of the same ID is because JS is duplicating my rows, so the ID # just gets duplicated along with it.

Comment: @user1562781: there is a note about that in `.clone()` documentation. So after clone - change id

Comment: multiple ids with the same name produce invalid html, wich might run fine but you should not count on it. Why not just use classes with the same name? Multiple instances are allowed there.

Comment: I honestly wasn't aware of that fact, but now that I know, I went back and fixed everything accordingly. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `:last` selector:

```
 var newElem = $('.ccinput:last').clone().attr('id', 'input' + newNum);
 $('.ccinput:last').after(newElem);
 $(".ccinput:last td:first").replaceWith( "<td>" + newNum + "</td>" );
```

or instead of `replaceWith()` you can try:

```
 $(".ccinput:last td:first").html(newNum).removeAttr('id');
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JaMnY/)

Comment: That works perfectly. And I went in and removed all the unnecessary IDs and replaced the necessary ones with class in order to have a proper HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

Not enough rep to comment, but this really should be a reply to your comment thread...

Your HTML "seems to run fine" except that you can only get the first element with a given ID because it's not running fine and is invalid HTML. In other words, your HTML does NOT run fine with duplicated IDs (because it's invalid HTML).

Instead of giving a row an ID and duplicating it, give it a class. That way your HTML will actually run fine (pending changes to your JavaScript to select by class instead of ID).